# Display and update text with Bokeh: settings glyph on update not working

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to write a web app that displays graphs with Bokeh and also displays formatted text retrieved from an API. The display dynamically changes with the content of the graph when the user clicks a button. Is there a standard way to format and present text, and then update it, with Bokeh?

I thought I could do this with text glyphs, but so far I am failing. Here's what I'm trying to do for the update action:

```
def update_graph(attrname, old, new):
    USER_ID = new

    use_df = get_user_df(new, cur, date_from, date_to)
    plot1.title = get_api_output(new, INSIGHT_DATE)

    textplot.text(3, 3, text=["hellllllo"], text_color="firebrick", text_align="center", text_font_size="20pt")

    source1.data['x'] = use_df[use_df['type'] == 0]['date'].values
    source1.data['y'] = use_df[use_df['type'] == 0]['value'].values
```

This mostly works fine the way it is. I grab some data from a remote DB with `get_user_df` and update `source1`, which works appropriately. Similarly the title gets updated as desired.

*However* no text glyph appears on `textplot` and no error appears in the console. What's going on and how can I dynamically adjust text glyphs on a plot?

Also here is the code I use to set up the plots in case that is relevant:

```
#plot utilities
def mtext(p, x, y, text):
    p.text(x, y, text=[text],
           text_color="firebrick", text_align="center", text_font_size="10pt")

#PLOTS

textplot = Figure(toolbar_location = None, title = 'API text', title_text_font_size='8pt')
mtext(textplot, randint(2, 5), randint(2, 5), 'annotation')

plot1 = Figure(toolbar_location = None, title = 'Distance (k)', title_text_font_size='8pt')
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = use_df[use_df['type'] == 0]['date'].values, y = use_df[use_df['type'] == 0]['value'].values))
plot1.circle('x', 'y', line_color=None, source = source1, color = 'pink', size = 20)
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If you can provide a complete script, I can take a quick look, but I can't spend the time to try to fill in all the gaps to be able to test something.